# How to use the Migration Tool with Single Sign On?

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, migration-tool

I've used the Ant Migration Tool previously, but only in an Org that allowed a username/password login.  Now I'm trying to get it to work for deployment to an Org that uses single sign on, but I can't find anything about how to configure the build.properties file for this.

Does anyone know how to configure Single Sign On credentials / deployment?

Thanks

Comment: The org doesn't have a regular account as a backup?

Comment: I thought SSO was all or nothing.  It makes sense you can designate accounts that are outside of it.  Thanks, I need to read more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be an account that accesses the org outside of their Single Sign On system. For instance, System Administrators really shouldn't be a part of a SSO system because if that system fails, no users can access Salesforce. Ideally, any deployments should also be done with an account like that.

Comment: Great thanks.  Looks like I need to read more about how SSO works.  I thought it was all or nothing...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have username & password then you can use session id in build.properties.